# AWS Storage Cost for a custom AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

How does AWS calculate the cost of a custom AMI?

If I would create an AMI which is based on Ubuntu 16.04, do I need to pay for the complete size of AMI (e.g. 4GB) or just the differences of my custom AMI to the base AMI (e.g. 0.4GB)

Answer (score 3):

AWS stores **whole** AMI as a single non-differential snapshot thus they charge for a full size of files in an image.